# Taking Modulo of Double NUmber

Tags: java, algorithm, module, double, precision

I have given two number `a` and `b`.I have to Calculate `(a^b)%1000000007`.How Can i calculate for floating point numbers. Ex:

```
a= 7.654 and b=10000
```

Here is my Code will `%` work :

```
 public static double super_pow(double A , long B){

          double o=1;

          while(B>0){

              if((B&1)!=0) o*=A;

              A*=A;
              B/=2;
              o%=mod;
              A%=mod;
          }

          return (o)%mod;
    }
```

Comment: hmm you reedited the question to completely different problem ... see [edit1] in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in Java you can use the % operator on floating point types.

You will have problems with the exponent though: You can't use `%` to reduce the intermediate results because modulo does not distribute over floating point multiplication: `(a*b)%c` is not `(a%c)*(b%c)`. If you try to compute 7.654^10000 directly you will get `infinity`; it exceeds the maximum value for `double`. Even if it didn't you couldn't trust the lowest digits of the result because they are pure noise created by rounding and representation error.

You could use a library that implements exact arithmetic, such as java.math.BigDecimal, but that will cost a lot in terms of execution time and memory. If you think you need to do this calculation as a part of a bigger problem, probably you should take a step back and find another way.

**Edit:** Here's the result with `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal[] divmod = new BigDecimal("7.654").pow(10000)
                             .divideAndRemainder(new BigDecimal("1000000007"))

return divmod[1].doubleValue() // I get 9.01287592373194E8
```

Answer (score 1):

In java you can use the modulo operation for floats/doubles ([How do I use modulus for float/double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947044/how-do-i-use-modulus-for-float-double))

If you have to calculate *(a^b)%1000000007* you can use `double` for `a` and `b` 
([biggest integer that can be stored in a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double/1848762)), this makes exponentiation easier, use the `pow()` method (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_pow.htm)

```
  import static java.lang.Math.pow;

  public static double super_pow(double A , double B){ //returns long and B is also double

      double pow;
      double mod = 1000000007.0;

      pow = Math.pow(A,B);
      mod = pow % 1000000007;
      return mod;
}
```

Alternatively you can typecast (*loss of precision possible !*) the result of *a^b* to `long` and then use

```
double pow = Math.pow(A,B);
long mod = (long) pow%1000000007L; // the 'L' is important see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737616/what-is-the-modulo-operator-for-longs-in-java
return mod; //return a long not double in function
```

[What is the modulo operator for longs in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737616/what-is-the-modulo-operator-for-longs-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

**Is `%` Modulo?**

That depends on language you are using. But In general floating point values does not know modulo operation. You can compute it on your own. Let assume positive floating numbers `a=7.654` and `b=10000.0` so

```
d = a/b = 0.0007654                               // division
r = d-floor(d) = (0.0007654-0.0) = 0.0007654      // remainder
r = r*b = (0.0007654*10000.0) = 7.654             // rescale back
```

- `floor(x)` rounds down to nearest less or equal number to `x`
- `d` holds the floating division result
- `r` holds the remainder (modulo)

Another example `a=123.456` and `b=65`

```
d = a/b = 1.8993230769230769230769230769231
r = (d-floor(d))*b = 58.456
```

This can be used for integer and decimal values of `a,b` but beware the floating point unit performs rounding and can loose precision after few digits... If I remember correctly 64 bit `double` variables are usually usable maximally up to `18` digits.

**[Edit1] hmm you reedited the question to completely different problem**

So you are searching for `modpow`. You can google for java implementation of `modpow`. For example here

- [Modular arithmetics and NTT (finite field DFT) optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18577076/2521214)

You can find mine implementation in C++ on 32 bit integer arithmetics but with static modulo prime with specific properties. Still if you change all the

```
if (DWORD(d)>=DWORD(p)) d-=p;
```

to `d=d%p;` it would work for any modulo. you will need `modpow,modmul,modadd,modsub`.

Comment: If the language lacks an operator for floating point modulo, its standard library likely has a function for it, like `fmod` in C

Comment: @Joni yep but its a good to know what and how it does anyway And what to be aware of... there were no language tags when I was answering so I do the math instead of suggesting lib