# To reach the target number from 0 in minimum number of steps

Tags: java, python, algorithm, mathematical-optimization

**Problem Statement:**
Find the minimum number of steps required to reach a target number x from 0 (zero), using only two operations: +1 *(add 1 to the number)* or *2 *(multiply 2 with the number)*.

**So here's the Logic that I came up with:**

The best way is to work backwards. Start from the number you need:

1. Subtract 1 if the number is odd.
2. Divide by 2 if the number if even.
3. Stop when you get to zero.

For example, for 29, you get 28, 14, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1, 0.

**And, here's what I have tried doing (Java 7):**

`kValues` is an array that has the `x` values for which the `steps` are needed to be computed and stored in an array called `result`.

```
static int[] countOperationsToK(long[] kValues) {
    int size = kValues.length,x,i,steps;
    int result[] = new int[size];

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        steps = 0;
        for (x = (int)kValues[i]; x != 0 ; ++steps)
        {
            if((x % 2) == 0)
                x /= 2;
            else x--;
        }
        result[i] = steps;
    }

    return result;
}
```

**My Problem:**

This is a Hackerrank question and I am supposed to write an efficient code. I was successful with 7/11 test cases and others were timed out. Since, it is a Hackerrank question, I can't change the function definition or the return type. That is the reason why I am converting from `long` to `int` in my `for` loop, in order to use `%` (modulus). I would like to know where I am going wrong. Is my algorithm taking too long to compute (for the number of values close to a million)? Which is obviously the case, but how do I alter my algorithm in order to pass all the test cases?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: any reason this is tagged python?

Comment: This is tagged under python too because, I think python can give a better solution. So, if by chance any python guy sees this code and be like "I can reduce the time complexity in seconds". So yeah... @Stael

Comment: What verdict you got ? TLE or WA ?

Comment: The cast is likely causing problems. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737616/what-is-the-modulo-operator-for-longs-in-java) to use modulo on `long`s.

Comment: I am getting "Terminated due to timeout" error

Answer (score 1):

```
for (x = (int)kValues[i]; x != 0 ; ++steps)
```

The fact that you are casting a long to an int is very suspicious. You might get a negative number when you do that.

Say `x == -2`: you divide it by 2 to give `-1`, then subtract 1 to give `-2`. You'll keep doing that indefinitely.

Just define `x` to be a `long`, and remove the cast.

Comment: If I do that, I cant use the modulus in my logic

Comment: @Prakhar why? `%` is defined for long. But you could simply test `(num & 1) == 0` alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's the working code. I had forgotten to append `L` while using the modulo. Silly mistake led to so much of typing. LOL!!

```
static int[] countOperationsToK(long[] kValues) {
    int size = kValues.length,i,steps;
    int result[] = new int[size];
    long x;

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        steps = 0;
        for (x = kValues[i]; x != 0 ; ++steps)
        {
            if((x % 2L) == 0)
                x /= 2L;
            else x -= 1L;
        }
        result[i] = steps;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: There is no need for those `L`s. Whenever you use a binary operator with long and int operands, the int will automatically be promoted to a long.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very short version, using bit-analysis:

```
static int[] countOperationsToK(long... input) {
    int result[] = new int[input.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        if (input[i] > 0)
            result[i] = Long.bitCount(input[i]) + 63 - Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(input[i]);
    return result;
}
```

The idea here is to look at the binary number, e.g. for 29 that is `11101`. There are 4 bits set, so we'd need to do `+1` four times, and the highest bit position is 4, so we need to left-shift (i.e. `*2`) four times, for a total of 8 operations: `+1`, `*2`, `+1`, `*2`, `+1`, `*2`, `*2`, `+1`.

```
numberOfBits = Long.bitCount(x)
highBitNumber = floor(log2(x)) = 63 - Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(x)
```

The `highBitNumber` part doesn't work if value is zero, hence the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

For input number x,

Minimum no. of Ops = (int)log2(x) + Long.BitCount(x)